# Expand by Arguments, UNIX

Tags: bash, shell, unix

I frequently run into commands which do not take multiple arguments well. I would like to know if there is a standard shell command for the following operation. I Named it expand, but I know there is already a different command called expand:

```
expand myCommand -option1 -option2 arg1 arg2 arg3 | suffix_operations_or_&
```

when run it would turn the above line into this:

```
myCommand -option1 -option2 arg1  | suffix_operations_or_&
myCommand -option1 -option2 arg2  | suffix_operations_or_&
myCommand -option1 -option2 arg3  | suffix_operations_or_&
```

Is there a name for this operation?

Comment: Do you mean like `xargs`?

Comment: @EtanReisner `xargs` can't easily execute a pipeline for each argument.

Comment: @EtanReisner `xargs` does the opposite, concatenate arguments

Comment: @Barmar Agreed, but it wasn't clear to me that `| suffix_operations_or_&` was actually a shell pipeline. It might have been though.

Comment: @ÁlvaroGutiérrez No, `xargs` takes standard input and converts it to command line arguments for a given command in the way you tell it to. So the above could be `printf %s\\n arg1 arg2 arg3 | xargs -L 1 myCommand -option1 -option2`. But as Barmar indicates that doesn't let you (natively at least) execute shell pipelines.

Comment: @ÁlvaroGutiérrez The key is the `-L 1` option, which tells it to do one input per iteration, instead of trying to combine them all.

Comment: @EtanReisner Also, `xargs` won't easily allow you to put each command in the background with `&`.

Comment: @Barmar Each command to an arbitrary limit based on data size? No. But in parallel? Sure, that's what `-P` is for. But yes a loop works for this just as well and is more generic.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Easiest way is a simple `for` loop:

```
for i in arg1 arg2 arg3
do
    myCommand -option1 -option2 "$i" | suffix_operations_or_ &
done
```

Comment: This worked for the scenario I was working on, and it appears to be general enough that you can add additional commands to the end. The image viewer I was using would open all the images in a single window where only 1 was visible at a time, and I wanted to look at every image at once. For i in *.png ...  eog "$1" &       worked.